# Behavior of <p> inside float

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="test">       
    <p>
      Floating behaves differently with  paragraphs. Floating behaves differently with  
      paragraphs. Floating behaves differently with  paragraphs.
    </p>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
#test{
    float:left;
    background-color: #222;
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #FFF;    
}
```

You may see at http://jsfiddle.net/fM4bE/ there is a space at the bottom of test div created by p /p. If we remove float:left this space disappears as if it wasn't any /p... Could anyone explain to me why?

Thank you

Comment: Read about [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the `float:left` being applied on the div, what you'd see is [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), where the bottom margins of the div and p merge:

> Parent and first/last child If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the
>   margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline
>   content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the
>   margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child,
>   then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the
>   parent.

However, the `float:left` creates a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), similar to what adding `overflow:auto` would do if you added it to the div in place of `float:left`. This allows the margins to not collapse.

> Block formatting contexts are important for the positioning (see
>   float) and clearing (see clear) of floats. The rules for positioning
>   and clearing of floats apply only to things within the same block
>   formatting context. Floats do not affect the layout of things in other
>   block formatting contexts, and clear only clears past floats in the
>   same block formatting context.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting